# SQL Server String combination

Tags: sql-server-2008

I will like to return a table of rows consist of all possible combination of a string in MS SQL 2008. For example string "01-02-03-04":

1. 01 - 02 - 03 - 04
2. 02 - 03 - 04
3. 01 - 03 - 04
4. 01 - 02 - 04
5. 01 - 02 - 03
6. 01 - 02
7. 01 - 03
8. 01 - 04
9. 02 - 03
10. 02 - 04
11. 03 - 04

Comment: I would like that too :)

Comment: You forgot "01", "02", "03" and "04". And, to be absolutely exact, the empty string too.

Comment: But i dun need "01", "02", "03" and "04" as well the empty string.

Comment: It's very nice of you to tell us that because that wasn't obvious enough from the phrase '*all possible* combination'. Are there any more particulars you've forgotten to mention? Does the string always have 4 items? Is the format fixed (four 2-digit groups delimited with hyphens)? Should it be verified before processing the string? You see, something could still be done about improving your question.

Comment: The format is fixed with 2-length element, but the element maybe different i.e "01-02-03", "02-03-05-09-10"

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @s varchar(150);
SET @s = '01-02-03-05-10';
WITH split AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(SUBSTRING(@s, number * 3 + 1, 2) AS varchar(150)) AS item,
    rn = number
  FROM master..spt_values
  WHERE type = 'P' AND number between 0 AND LEN(@s) / 3
),
combined AS (
  SELECT
    item,
    rn,
    itemcnt = 1
  FROM split
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    item = CAST(c.item + '-' + n.item AS varchar(150)),
    n.rn,
    itemcnt = c.itemcnt + 1
  FROM split n
    INNER JOIN combined c ON n.rn > c.rn
)
SELECT *
FROM combined
WHERE itemcnt > 1
ORDER BY 1
```